# Can't populate RecylcerView Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I tried to follow how to build a recyclerview for my class project, but for some reason, I can't do it. I'm not sure of what I am missing. Ideas?

EDIT: I went ahead and added more code upon reuqest

The code that is relevant:

```
String selectedVenue;
String id;
String currentuser;
String venueType;
boolean canComment;
ArrayList<Comments> commentList = new ArrayList<>();

ParseGeoPoint venueLocation;
ParseGeoPoint userLocation;

Button commentButton;
RecyclerView commentRecView;
SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

CommentDetailAlt commentDetailAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_feed_alt);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    try{
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    currentuser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername();


    mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefreshAlt);
    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    commentList.clear();
                    GetFeed download = new GetFeed();
                    download.execute();
                }
            }

    );

    commentRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comment_list);
    commentRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    commentDetailAdapter = new CommentDetailAlt(commentList, this);
    commentRecView.setAdapter(commentDetailAdapter);

    UserFeedAlt.GetFeed download = new GetFeed();
    download.execute();

}




public class GetFeed extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    ArrayList<Comments> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> contentFeed = new ParseQuery<>("UserCommentary");
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> drinks = new ParseQuery<>("venueDrinks");
        if(venueType.equals("House Parties")){
            //Query for Bars
            drinks.whereEqualTo("venueName",selectedVenue);
            drinks.whereEqualTo("venueID",id);
            drinks.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
            drinks.setLimit(2);
            try{
                List<ParseObject>qReply = drinks.find();
                if(qReply.size()>0){
                    for(ParseObject item : qReply){
                        String drinkName = item.getString("venueDrinkName");
                        float drinkPrice = (float) item.getInt("venuePriceDrink");
                        boolean isImage = item.getBoolean("isImage");
                        Bitmap bmp;
                        Comments drink = new Comments(String.valueOf(drinkPrice),selectedVenue,id,drinkName,0,true);
                        if(isImage){
                            ParseFile dataPhoto = item.getParseFile("imgFile");
                            byte[] data = dataPhoto.getData();
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0 ,data.length);
                            drink.photoFile = bmp;
                        }
                        temp.add(drink);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    String comment = "Nothing Here";
                    String owner = "Mr. Smith";
                    int count = 0;
                    String id = "Test";
                    String venueName = "Smith's Mayback's";
                    Comments newComment = new Comments(comment,venueName,id,owner,count,false);
                    temp.add(newComment);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            contentFeed.whereEqualTo("venueName",selectedVenue);
            contentFeed.whereEqualTo("venueID",id);
            contentFeed.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
            try{
                List<ParseObject>qReply = contentFeed.find();
                if(qReply.size()>0){
                    for(ParseObject item : qReply){
                        String commentOwner = item.getString("owner");
                        String commentContent = item.getString("comment");
                        boolean isImage = item.getBoolean("image");
                        Bitmap bmp;
                        Comments comment = new Comments(commentContent,selectedVenue,id,commentOwner,0,false);
                        if(isImage){
                            ParseFile dataPhoto = item.getParseFile("imgFile");
                            byte[] data = dataPhoto.getData();
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0 ,data.length);
                            comment.photoFile = bmp;
                        }
                        temp.add(comment);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        else if(venueType.equals("Bars")){
            //Query for HouseParties
            contentFeed.whereWithinMiles("Location",userLocation,0.00284091);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        commentList = temp;
        Log.i("AppInfo", String.valueOf(commentList.size()));
        commentDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);



    }


}
```

Comment: Where are you setting adapter to RecyclerView? And check that you have added any kind of LayoutManager with the RecyclerView.

Comment: Ah yes, I set that in the onCreate method as `commentRecView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comment_list);
        commentRecView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        commentDetailAdapter = new CommentDetailAlt(commentList, this);
        commentRecView.setAdapter(commentDetailAdapter);`

Comment: You also will need to notify the adapter after the AsyncTask is completed

Comment: using this? `commentList = temp;
            commentDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);`

Comment: From your comment you are calling adapter with 'commentList' variable. And in AsyncTask you are adding items to 'temp' variable. Are you sure the arrayList is not null or empty?

Comment: Do you you really need the AsyncTask? Parse has a `findInBackground`, I thought

Comment: It does have a find in background, I just wanted to try a different approach.

Comment: Yes the items are non-empy becuase I check at the end of the backgroundtask.

Comment: Well, AsyncTask is more difficult to manage to "return data" to where you need it. Please do [edit] your question to include the relevant activity code for where you set up the adapter and execute the task

Comment: Try to check the variable size before calling adapter. I dont think you are calling the adapter with right variable. If you can post the entire code. That would be helpful

Comment: I went ahead and added all the relevant code, I tried to see if it was making it to the the adapter turns out it was.

Comment: Have you find out the answer? If not try to execute the asynctask before setting adapter in oncreate. I added it to answer for you clearance.

Answer (score 0):

add the onPostExecute function to AsyncTask and notify the adapter

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     commentDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

onPostExecute calls after the background process completed (coz array might be empty before that), and onPostExecute can access the main thread.

Comment: I added the code, for some reason this didn't fix it either.

Comment: did u make sure the data array is not empty

Comment: Yeap its not. I checked with the parse server and the size of the array after the on post execute method. 2 items should exist

Answer (score 0):

Original:

```
commentDetailAdapter = new CommentDetailAlt(commentList, this);
commentRecView.setAdapter(commentDetailAdapter);

UserFeedAlt.GetFeed download = new GetFeed();
download.execute();
```

Change that to

```
UserFeedAlt.GetFeed download = new GetFeed();
download.execute();

commentDetailAdapter = new CommentDetailAlt(commentList, this);
commentRecView.setAdapter(commentDetailAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, turns out I am pretty sure that the custom object `Comments` is actually the source of the problem. I am currently deloping a way to fix it.